# How to save/download MP4 in Safari (instead of playing the file in quick time pro player)

Tags: php, macos

I have uploaded a .mp4 file with php in a upload folder. Now i am downloading it with download link. It is downloading properly on a windows system in safari browser. But on mac system the video file is playing with quicktime pro player. While i just want to download it.
but it is playing by default. It is the issue only on safari browser. Is there any way to change this. so that it will not play with quicktime pro player by default.

Answer (score 1):

That's *probably* because you're just linking to the file so if the user's computer has software to handle it, it will choose to run it by default (assuming the user has their computer set up that way).

You can force the browser to show the download dialog prompt if you use the proper headers:

```
 header("Cache-Control: public");
 header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
 header("Content-Type: video/mpeg");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code,

```
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Pragma: public');   // required
        header('Expires: 0');    // no cache
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file)).' GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: private',false);
        header('Content-Type: octet/stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));  // provide file size
        header('Connection: close');
        readfile($file);    // push it out
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: same thing is here. video file is downloading as well as playing with quicktime pro player.

Comment: Please change the Content type as `'octet/stream'` or `'binary'` and try.